# How to get property of non-object?

Tags: php, html, laravel

my referral system works perfectly, but I would like to put the name, username or email address of the referral in the page html Ex: {$ username}. On my controller I have "redirect" currently working, but if I put {$ username} it returns "undefined variable", but if I change it to "View" {$ username} works, but the registration is done with " admin "as referred to by default.

My Controller:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RefController extends Controller
{
    public function index( $username )
     {
    $user = User::where( 'username', $username )->first();

    return ( is_null( $user ) )
        ? redirect( '/' )
        : redirect( '/register' )->withCookie( cookie()->forever( 'referrer_id', $user->id ) );
     }
}
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/user/{username}', 'RefController@index' );
```

**Updated**

My RegisterController:

```
 protected function create(array $data) {
    if($data['gender']=='male'){

        $avatar_path = 'boy.png';
    }
    else
        { 
            $avatar_path = 'girl.png';
        }
        $referrer = User::find( Cookie::get( 'referrer_id' ) );

        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'avatar' => $avatar_path,
            'gender' => $data['gender'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'passaport' => $data['passaport'],
            'country' => $data['country'],
            'city' => $data['city'],
            'state' => $data['state'],
            'address' => $data['address'],
            'postcode' => $data['postcode'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'referrer_id' => (is_null($referrer )) ? 1 : $referrer->id,
        ]);
```

**Updated**

My Migrations add_Ref_to_user_table:

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AddReferrerToUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) 
        {
                $table->integer('referrer_id')->unsigned()->default(1)->after('id');
                $table->foreign('referrer_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table)
         {
                $table->dropForeign(['referrer_id']);
                $table->dropColumn( 'referrer_id' );
        });
    }
}
```

And the code that returns the error is this:

```
{{ Auth::user()->name }}
```

**UPDATED**

I got help and patience from @Caddy DZ changing `return view ('auth.register') -> with` to

```
return view ('/auth/register')
```

Comment: You can't show the authenticated user's name on the registration page because there is no authenticated user

Comment: {{ Auth::user()->name ?? "" }}

Comment: yes I thought about it but I don't know how to show it but I need to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a referral system, a user should get a 404 for inserting a non existing referral in the url

Use `firstOrFail`

```php
public function index($username)
{
    $user = User::where('username', $username)->firstOrFail();
    return view('auth.register')->with([
        'referrer_id' => $user->id,
        'username' => $username
    ]);
}
```

then display the username in the view like this

```html
{{ $username }}
```

Assuming you do have a name column in your database table

```php
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name'); // Must have this
    $table->string('username')->unique(); // Must have this unique
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

#### Update

Replace this code

```php
'referrer_id' => (is_null($referrer )) ? 1 : $referrer->id,
```

By the actual integer stored in the Cookie

```php
'referrer_id' => $referrer,
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200106/discussion-on-answer-by-caddy-dz-how-to-get-property-of-non-object).

Answer (score 2):

If this route is accessible only by authenticated users - try to add auth middleware to it.

```
Route::get('/user/{username}', 'RefController@index' )->middleware('auth');
```

Try to change code in your controller to the following:

```
return ( is_null( $user ) )
        ? redirect( '/' )
        : view( 'auth.register', compact( 'referrer_id', 'user' ) );
```

In `auth.register` view try to get `{{ $user->name }}` instead of `{{ Auth::user()->name }}`.

Comment: is the route for users to register, wanted to show the name of the recruiter

Comment: If you need to show name of the recruiter - you could pass recruiter id in URI, then resolve this recruiter user by it's id and then you will be able to show his name.

Comment: If you use `{{ Auth::user()->name }}` then you are trying to get username of the user who is making request to your server.

Comment: yes, i used why my url is domain.com/user/jhonn ... this page goes for registration and right below I want to show the name of "jhonn"

Comment: error " Use of undefined constant user - assumed 'user' "